# Error occurred during the signature verification for debian buster repositories

Tags: linux, debian, synaptic-pkg-mgr

I am trying to refresh repository indexes using Synsptic Package Manager and getting the following error.

> An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is
>   not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error:
>   http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1
>   required for verification, but neither seems installed
>
> An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is
>   not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error:
>   http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease:
>   gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems
>   installed
>
> An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is
>   not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error:
>   http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or
>   gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
>
> Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease 
>   gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems
>   installed
>
> Failed to fetch
>   http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease
>   gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems
>   installed
>
> Failed to fetch
>   http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  gpgv,
>   gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
>
> Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

Even I have gpgv, gpgv2 and gpgv1 installed.
This error does not happen on *`sudo apt update`* but synaptic throws out this error.
I am new to debian and I do not understand how to resolve this. Please help me out.